# How to test directives in modularized angularjs scope?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine, modularity

I am trying to test a directive which is defined in a sub-module of another submodule of the root module. I am unable to access the scope variables defined in the controller of the directive. The problem seems to lie in accessing the scope from inside the test.

The main module is named `oppia` and it has a submodule named `stateEditorModule` and this submodule also has a submodule named `stateContentEditorModule`. I have tried injecting `$scope` instead of `$rootScope` but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the test code:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('oppia');
    module('stateEditorModule');
    module('stateContentEditorModule');
  });

    outerScope = $rootScope.$new();
    var elem = angular.element(
      '<state-content-editor>' +
      '</state-content-editor>');
    var compiledElem = $compile(elem)(outerScope);
    outerScope.$digest();
    ctrlScope = compiledElem[0].getControllerScope();
  }));

  fit('should start with the content editor not being open', function() {
    expect(ctrlScope.contentEditorIsOpen).toBe(false);
  });
```

The `contentEditorIsOpen` variable is defined in the directive's scope.

The `contentEditorIsOpen` is inaccessible with the current state of the code.

I am stuck on this for a quite long and I would be grateful if someone could provide a solution or point to the documentation on how to test a multi-modular AngularJS app.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't test the directive itself. Instead, you would test the controller of that directive.

This means you need to register the controller in DI. Then you can get the controller of that directive directly through DI (without creating and compiling the direcitve), provide an initial scope to that controller, call a function, and assert some vars on that scope to be a specific value.

Example from the doc: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller

If you are using components instead of directives, check out this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#unit-testing-component-controllers

UPDATE:

> I used the controllerAs property of the directive to give a name to the controller as stateContentEditorController

`controllerAs` only creates an alias for that controller in the scope of the template, but it won't register it in the DI (dependency injection) module, so you can't retrieve it from the DI system.

What I suggested was to write your directive and your controller separately and register your controller using `angular.module('moduleName').controller('controllerName', [...])`. Then in your directive definition object just write `{controller: 'controllerName', ...}`. This way you can retrieve the controller in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I used the `controllerAs` property of the directive to give a name to the controller as `stateContentEditorController`. But the test gives out an error saying `Argument 'stateContentEditorController' is not a function, got undefined`. I used `ctrlScope = $controller('stateContentEditorController', {$scope: outerScope});` and commented out the directive compiling part. I think the scope I am providing is incorrect? What are your suggestions?

Comment: @theJediCode see updated post. Maybe you can provide a runnable fiddle of your code if you still having trouble making it work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am still unable to retrieve the controller. I separated the directive and the controller as asked by you but still no luck. The controller is returning undefined. [Here](https://github.com/YashJipkate/oppia/tree/modularity-restructure/core/templates/dev/head/pages/state-editor/state-content-editor) is the github folder on my fork.